# How does the BufferedImage.getRGB(int, int, int, int, int[], int, int) work?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, rgb, bufferedimage

So i've been following a tutorial on youtube for game programming, and this code popped up:
`bufferedImageObject.getRGB(int, int, int, int, int[], int, int);` and the explanation that was given was that, basically, the .getRGB() takes sets the pixel data of the bufferedImageObject to the int[] that you pass through the method parameters.

So, here's my question: how does that exactly work? like, obviously the getRGB method modifies the int[] right? i tried doing that in a test program, but nothing changed. so, how exactly does the getRGB method store the data to the int[] array passed? and, on top of that, what is the limit to this? i've never run into this sort of thing, but i can see the endless possibilities available!

Thanks for any insight, and please feel free to edit my question, as i'm awful at phrasing questions!

EDIT:
This is a program that I just tested the idea with:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t = 10;
        test(t);
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    public static void test(int i) {
        i = 15;
    }
}
```

the value printed out was '10'. So, in this case, how could i modify the `t` variable with the `test()` method? short of `t = test(t);` with test returning 15....

Comment: That's exactly how it should work. Looking at the source code, the method uses the array that you pass in, unless it is `null` (in which case it creates an array itself). It's helpful if you post your test program, maybe there something going on in there.

Comment: that didnt specifically answer my question though. i've done some c++, and i know that you can pass a variable through a method, and that method, whether it be in another class or not, can modify the actual variable itself, changing the value where the variable is called. i was not aware java does that, and i'm wondering how to force it to do that? like, this method clearly does, but how? does it only work with arrays?

Comment: Was the `int[]` you passed as an argument large enough to hold all of the values?  I think this line is the most informative of what the method is doing: The RGB value at (x, y) is: `pixel   = rgbArray[offset + (y-startY)*scansize + (x-startX)];`

Comment: yeah it was. but, so, if you pass an int[] as a parameter, the method you pass it to can modify the original variable? i guess thats my question... and if yes, can you do that with any variable? if no, how would you?

Comment: Java uses "pass-by-value" which is confusing to a lot of people.  _All_ objects in Java are actually pointers, so when you pass the _value_ of a pointer, you can modify the values that this pointer points to.  Arrays are objects and thus you _can_ modify the contents of the array by passing it as an argument.

Comment: This has no effect on the parameter passed: `public static int[] changeArr(int[] arr){ arr = new int[2]; arr[0] = 0; arr[1] = 1; return arr;}` This _does_ have an effect on the passed array (and may cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`): `public static int[] changeArr(final int[] arr){ arr[0] = 0; arr[1] = 0; return arr;}`

Comment: Jared is correct. But you said that you tried it in a test program and it didn't work. There's probably some issue in that test program.

Comment: see the edit, i feel it explains a bit better

Comment: In your edited view you use a primitive which is _not_ an object.  So as I said, Java uses pass-by-value, so the you just modified the copy of the primitive `int i` and thus had no affect on the value of the `int` you passed to the method.  Try my example (with an `int` array of size two).  You will see the two different behaviors.

Comment: If you're familiar with C, then take a look at the following two functions and realize the difference: `void changeInt(int *i){ int a; i = &a; *i = 2}` vs. `void changeInt(int *i){ *i = 2;}`.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is an absolute, but almost _always_ variables to methods should be declared as `final` (same as `const` in C/C++).  This will prevent you from redefining passed variables as if you thought that would have an effect on the passed variable.

Comment: I have assumed, thus far, that you understand that this `getRGB` method returns _several_ pixels and that _each_ pixel returned is an `int` value of an RGB value.  If you want to examine each pixel you _have_ to use `Color thisColor = new Color(intRGBValue)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this whole questions probably boils down to you not understanding Java's pass-by-value semantics.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t = 10;
    test(t);
    System.out.println(t);
}

public static void test(int i) {
    i = 15;
}
```

> So, in this case, how could I modify the `t` variable with the `test()` method? short of `t = test(t);` with `test` returning `15`?

The simple answer is you can't.

You cannot write a method that will modify the value of a local variable in another method.  It is simply not possible in Java.

And **that** is why we insist on saying that Java parameter passing is "pass-by-value".

---

So back to your original question, given this:

```
   bufferedImageObject.getRGB(int, int, int, int, int[], int, int);
```

Question: how does `getRGB` return the values in the array parameter?

Answer: it *copies* the pixel values from the image into the array.

Question: how is that (still) pass-by-value?

Answer: the parameter being passed (by value!!) is the reference to the array.  The `getRGB` is modifying the array.  But it is not modifying the array reference.

---

> I tried doing that in a test program, but nothing changed.

I would need to >>see<< that test program before I could explain that.  But I'd bet money that the explanation was consistent with what I've written above.

Comment: I think this is the confusion, but if the OP passes a valid `int[]` as a parameter, it should be properly modified.

Comment: I'll be totally honest.  I have had problems with passing an array to library functions before.  I would not be surprised if there is a bug in the `getRGB` method.  If so, you should make damn sure it's a bug and not your fault and, if so, submit a bug report.  But before you do that, as I originally suggested, you should make sure you fully understand the documentation: `pixel   = rgbArray[offset + (y-startY)*scansize + (x-startX)];` <-- I think this is most likely to be the source of the bug (i.e. not understanding what this means).

Comment: I would be **extremely** surprised if there were still bugs in getRGB.  The BufferedImage class has been around since Java 1.2, and bugs would most likely have shown up in thousands of other peoples' code before now.

Comment: I hope the part where I said "make damn sure" it _is_ a bug would have alluded to the fact that I doubt there is a bug.

Comment: this answer is fantastic! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jared - I hope that the part where I said "I would be extremely surprised" is enough the tell the OP to not even waste his time trying to confirm a (99.99% likely) non-existent bug. It is a **red herring**.  Cappiche?? Comprendez??